# How do i output assembly code data back into a c++ array?

Tags: c++, assembly, masm, inline-assembly

I'm working on a program using inline assembly (have to use it) and c++, where I input a string and save it in a buffer array, and then the assembly code counts how many instances of each character in the string there is, and then inserts that data back into a different array called CountBuffer.

Since I'm only using a-z, A-Z, and 0-9, if I subtract the smallest character decimal values (48,65,97) from the current character decimal value I figured I can get an array index and then just insert and increment the times that character occurs in that index.

But how do I insert that occurrence value back into the c++ CountBuffer array? Do I use lea or mov? In addition, since A-Z,a-z,0-9 are not completely next to each other on the ascii table, how do I put them in the array so that there's no empty indexes?

This is my first time working with inline assembly, so I may be totally headed in the wrong direction with this entire project, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for your time!

```
//C++ INPUT STRING FUNCTION

class BaseClass
{
private:
     const int characterNumber = 127; //Max number of characters
     cont int asciiNumber = 59; //59 because A-Z, a-z, 0-9
     char InputBuffer[characterNumber];
     char CountBuffer[asciiNumber];
public:

     InputData()
     {
          string sentence;
          cout << "Enter a sentence to have its characters counted: " << endl;
          cin.getline(InputBuffer, characterNumber);
     }
```

```
//FUNCTION TO COUNT INSTANCES OF EACH CHARACTER 

     CountData()
     {
          char LocalBuffer[characterNumber];
          char LocalCountBuffer[asciiNumber];

//CREATING LOCAL BUFFERS SO ASSEMBLY CAN WORK WITH IT?

          for (int i = 0; i < characterNumber; i++)
          {
               LocalBuffer[i] = InputBuffer[i];
          }

          for (int i = 0; i < asciiNumber; i++)
          {
               CountBuffer[i] = LocalCountBuffer[i];
          }
```

```
//ASSEMBLY CODE PART
          _asm
          {
               mov ecx, 127
               lea si, [LocalBuffer]
           loop1:
               mov ax, [si]
               cmp ax, 'a'
               ja lowercase
               cmp ax, 'z'
               jb lowercase
               cmp ax, 'A'
               ja uppercase
               cmp ax, 'Z'
               jb uppercase
               cmp ax, '0'
               ja number
               cmp ax, '9'
               jb number
               inc si
               loop loop1

//PART WHERE I ACTUALLY COUNT INSTANCES AND RECORD BACK INTO ARRAY

               lowercase:
                    sub ax, 97

                    ;Want to do something like mov dl, [CountBuffer+ax]
                    ; Then inc dl
                    ;Then mov [CountBuffer+ax],dl

                    ;How do i access the CountBuffer array?


                    ; uppercase:
                    ;same for this label

                    ; number:
                    ; as well as for this label

                    ;HOW DO I GET THEM TO BE NEXT TO BE CONSECUTIVE INDEXES IN THE COUNT ARRAY
          }
     }


};
```

Comment: Your code looks broken; addresses are 32-bit if you're using Visual C++.  `[CountBuffer+ax]` is not even a valid addressing mode but `[CountBuffer+eax]` is.  Also, `mov ax, [si]` is a 2-byte load but presumably your input buffer holds single-byte ASCII characters, not wide character.

Comment: Also, `cmp ax, 'z'` / `jb lowercase` is totally broken. You want `if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')` but you implemented `||` instead.  Also note that if you assume alphabetic or numeric digit, `c >= 'a'` definitely means lower-case.  All the higher character values above `'z'` are not letters or numeral digits.  Use a debugger and single-step your code / look at register values to see what's happening.

Comment: I changed `lea si, [buffer]` to `lea esi, [buffer]`  , and `mov ax, [si]` to `mov al, [si]`. Do i need to use any movzx commands since i'm working with 32 bit?

Comment: yeah, you want `movzx eax, byte ptr [esi]` to do an 8-bit load using a 32-bit addressing mode.  That way you can safely use `eax` as part of another addressing mode.  Don't ever use 16-bit registers in addressing modes in 32-bit code.  Your code presumably has other bugs too, but those are the ones I noticed first in a quick look.

Comment: Okay thanks!  If i need to do what you said and use a conditional "and" statement, is there an equivalent in assembly, or do i just need to use conditional jumps?

Comment: Just lay out you branching to implement the right logic, like have to fall through both branches to reach the lower-case block or something.  Or do your range-check with `c-'a' < 'z'-'a'` using sub + cmp/jb.  (Or `lea` into a different register to avoid destroying the input)

Comment: Yup, there's no real reason to categorize bytes on input, just count everything and only print the entries you care about.  You might as well use `add dword ptr [edx+eax], 1` instead of load/inc/store.